# Kotlin interface with generic - Inteface method with vararg generic param cannot be overridden in implementing class

Tags: kotlin

Strange Kotlin problem.

In the first example (Iface1 and StringsExample) Kotlin does shows an error on the StringsExample.findById method because it does not like the interface having a  vararg generic, as far as I can tell.

The first second example (the below two classes) works properly.

I even tried it online in the Kotlin Playground and it gives an error: https://pl.kotl.in/iUTa0PZ88

How do I do this?

```kotlin
interface Iface1<T, K> {
    fun findById(vararg id: K): List<T>
}

class StringsExample: Iface1<String, Int> {
    override fun findById(vararg id: Int): List<String> {
        return listOf("not ok");
    }
}

interface Iface2<T, K> {
    fun findById(vararg id: Int): List<T>
}

class StringExampleGood: Iface2<String,  Int> {
    override fun findById(vararg id: Int): List<String> {
        return listOf("ok");
    }
}
```

EDIT - Note that the class is generated and while I can specify an interface that it implements I have no control over how the methods are generated, so I can't work around this by modifying the implementing class.

Comment: The `K` type-parameter in `Iface2` is entirely unused btw.

Comment: It's just an example...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be [a longstanding bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9495/vararg-and-substitution-of-primitives-for-type-parameters) in Kotlin. The problem is that the vararg `Int` parameter is being interpreted as an `IntArray` instead of an `Array<Int>`. In Java, this would be similar to trying to override `K[]` with `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`.

From [a discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/primitive-vararg-failed-to-override-generic-vararg/4453) back in 2017, one solution is to use `Int?` to force the use of `Array<Int?>`. The downside is this forces you to now handle nullability, but that problem should be limited to the specific method override.

```kotlin
interface IFace<K, R> {

    fun findByIds(vararg ids: K): List<R>
}

class IntStringExample : IFace<Int?, String> {

    override fun findByIds(vararg ids: Int?): List<String> {
        TODO("Not implemented yet.")
    }
}
```

But I think a better solution is to change `findByIds` to accept a `List<K>` and then define an *extension function* to give a varargs overload.

```kotlin
fun <K, R> IFace<K, R>.findByIds(vararg ids: K): List<R> {
    return findByIds(listOf(*ids))
}

interface IFace<K, R> {

    fun findByIds(ids: List<K>): List<R>
}

class IntStringExample : IFace<Int, String> {

    override fun findByIds(ids: List<Int>): List<String> {
        TODO("Not implemented yet.")
    }
}
```

Comment: See EDIT - Note that the class is generated and while I can specify an interface that it implements I have no control over how the methods are generated, so I can't work around this by modifying the implementing class.

Comment: "*so I can't work around this by modifying the implementing class*" -- The second solution in my answer changes the interface. If the implementation is generated from the interface, then the change will propagate.

Comment: Implementation is not generated from the interface

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand what you mean by, "*Note that the class is generated and while **I can specify an interface that it implements***".

Comment: https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/  - Jooq generates the class based on the database table. I can specify and interface / superclass to add to that generated class, but I cannot modify the methods that it generates (wrt the parameters and such)

Comment: In that case, I don't think I can help. You may want to ask a new question that's more specific to your actual problem (i.e., include a proper [mre], tag your question with the appropriate technologies, explain up front that you have no control over/don't know how to control the interface method's parameters, etc.). This question is very general, which is why you got answers applicable to Kotlin in general rather than jOOQ specifically.

Answer (score 1):

- In Kotlin, a `vararg x: T` [parameter is semantically identical](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) to `x: Array<out T>`.
- Updating the implementation of `findById` accordingly results in code that [does compile and run just fine](https://pl.kotl.in/QkU1y7lOb):

  ```
  class StringsExample: Iface1<String, Int> {
      override fun findById(id: Array<out Int>): List<String> {
          return listOf("not ok");
      }
  }
  ```
- As for *"why?"* - While I'm not a Kotlin expert, after playing around in Godbolt, I noticed something:

  - In Kotlin, the "`Int`" type  refers to both the `int` primitive value-type *and also* the `java.lang.Integer` boxed type.
  - When a class has a (non-implementing) `findById` member using the same syntax as the interface, then the `Int` type is mapped to the primitive value type, so `varargs id: Int` is `Array<out Int>` is *really* just `int[]`.
  - But when a class has a `findById` member that is mapped to that generic `interface`  method then it has to use the boxed type (`Integer`), not the primitive type, for the array element, because Kotlin inherits the JVM's inability to use value-types as generic type parameter arguments because they cannot be type-erased.

    - So in this case, it's `Integer[]`, not `int[]` - and `Integer[]` is not compatible with `int[]`.
    - ...but using the `vararg` modifier with `Int` seems to force the compiler to always (and only) prefer the `int[]` interpretation instead of `Integer[]`.
    - ...so using an explicit `Array<out T>` type is the only way to force the compiler to use the correct type.

Comment: Note one "issue" with this approach is that if you have a reference to `StringsExample` instead of `Iface1<String, Int>`, then you won't be able to use the vararg feature anymore (i.e., `val foo = StringsExample(); foo.findById(1, 2, 3);` will fail to compile).

Comment: @Slaw It is unfortunate that Kotlin doesn't support "explicit implementation" of interfaces like C# does, because that would allow for the interface to be implemented correctly (i.e. without `vararg`) by using a hidden method, while still allowing for an identically-named method _with_ the `vararg` param, but which wouldn't be exactly mapped to the interface. Ho-hum.

Comment: See EDIT - Note that the class is generated and while I can specify an interface that it implements I have no control over how the methods are generated, so I can't work around this by modifying the implementing class.

Comment: @mikeb Does your build-system have any kind of escape-hatch or way to "patch" auto-generated source files? There's usually a way to do this because stuff like this happens in every language out there.

Comment: Not for this particular case, I submitted an issue for it though